# Display Data Values without Browser Page Refresh in Angular

Tags: angular

The scenario:
I am getting the data in Json format from service call, and I render them on the web page in Angular2 component. But when user performs any delete or update operation, the values should automatically update without refreshing the page in Angular2 SPA

Comment: The behavior you are describing is the natural one for angular's data manipulation.

Comment: @LeonardoNeninger can you help with an example for the above scenario ?

Comment: Can you copy here a json example of your data and your component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming getting the data, deleting and updating the data is different API calls. If thats the case, the best approach I think would be to use something like a PubSub Service where DELETE and UPDATE would publish an event upon success and GET's would subscribe to that event. So, whenever a new event is published, your data bound to the GET call will be updated. You may use something like https://github.com/sqlProvider/angular2-pubsub